# Click on image and delete it from folder

Tags: php, html

I have different pages and different folders with images (one folder to each page), user use a form to send images to folder.
I want to exclude an image clicking on it if logged.
I can check if logged like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {}
```

But I don't know how to do a single file.php that will exclude any of these images. I thought something like this:

```
 $directorys = "images/uploads/logos/";
    $images = glob($directorys . "*.jpg");
    foreach($images as $image)
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
            echo '<form action="deleteimage.php" name="configuracoes" method="POST"><li><img src="'.$image.'" width="150" height="70" /></li></a></form>';
        } else{
            echo '<li><img src="'.$image.'" width="150" height="70" /></li>';
        }
     }
```

can someone help me in how I will pass the image name and folder name as parameter to use a single excludeimage.php?

Comment: I do not have excludeimage.php I dont know what I have to do to send param imagename and foldername. I mean remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QueryString` to send imagename as parameter:

```
$directorys = "images/uploads/logos/";
$images = glob($directorys . "*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image)
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
        echo '<form action="excludeimage.php?imagename=$image" name="configuracoes" method="POST"><li><img src="'.$image.'" width="150" height="70" /></li></a></form>';
    } else {
        echo '<li><img src="'.$image.'" width="150" height="70" /></li>';
    }
}
```

excludeimage.php code:

```
if(isset($_GET['imagename'])
{
     unlink($_GET['imagename']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, please can I send 2 parameters?

Comment: This form just made all images very very bigger, can you please help? I added style="height:70;width:150;" to the form but didn't worked